# Storing post meta data in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I just have a question regarding storing of meta data on wp_postmeta in wordpress. 
I already understand how to store data on the table, by using add_post_meta() and to get the data by using get_post_meta().. Basically I store meta key by using underscore and a string. example "_this_varible". and I store meta value using any data from metabox. 
My question are: 
1.) Is there a problem if I do not store meta keys variable with underscore? for example _this_variable ? 
2.) Is it ok if I store dates on the meta_key? I'm still confused on this part. 
3.) I was thinking on storing multiple meta data on wp_postmeta with the same post_id. Is there's no problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

1. start meta key with a underscore if you want to use a custom meta box for the input of the value -- it wont appear in the custom field box
2. you can store dates in the meta value....why would you want to make this a key? keys should be common to posts so you can pull reliably.
3. as many as you want!

Comment: I was thinking of storing dates with equivalent holiday,. so for example. 1/1/2014 is new year. I need to query that holiday based on the date given.

Comment: is this something dynamic for each post? so the post is about the holiday or similar and you will have a range of posts?

Comment: the post title is the country and in that post I stored all dates and holidays,. so for a single post it has a multiple dates and holidays,. I need to query those holidays based on the dates

Comment: hmm, ok i could see that working, depends on how you intend to use it, so key = 'new_year' value="1/1/2014"  no problem at all....i suppose you could save the date as the key but it mighten like the / (it goes through wordpress functions to save to database rather than direct write). try and see i suppose.